# Docker container ps or ls doesn't show running Containers

Tags: docker

Here is an example on my CLI:

```
$ docker pull hello-world
$ docker run hello-world
```

It shows empty when `ls/ps`

```
$ docker container ls
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$ docker container ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

It shows up only when I use `-a` but it'd suggest the containers are actually not actively running.

```
$ docker container ls -a
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
    96c3e42ae83a        hello-world         "/hello"                 11 seconds ago      Exited (0) 8 seconds ago                            jovial_rosalind
    dcaed0ba308f        registry            "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   42 minutes ago      Created                    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: That's expected behavior.That container meant to show your set up is working.At the end of message gives an example how to run interactive container `To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash`

Comment: Here is the [source](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/blob/master/Dockerfile.build) you can customize it if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your container exited right away. Is it meant to be interactive? (like running bash, or needing any user interaction?) if it is, you should run it like this to attach a terminal to it:

```
docker run -ti hello-world
```

If not, what does your `hello` program do? If it is not something that will keep running, then the container will stop whenever it exits.

Also keep in mind that, unless you pass `docker run` the `-d`/`--detach` flag, it will only return after the container has stopped - so if it returns right away, that means your container has already stopped.

You may want to use one of these to get a bash shell in the container to debug your problem:

```
docker run -ti hello-world bash
```

```
docker run --entrypoint bash -ti hello-world
```

To understand the difference between them, you can read [the documentation on ENTRYPOINT and COMMAND](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options).

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is due to daemon. `docker run -ti hello-world bash` shows `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was an example container - it isn't meant to be a long-running container, so that's the expected behaviour. That container also does not bundle a shell, so running it with `--entrypoint bash` or `--entrypoint sh` giving that error is also expected. Your `docker run hello-world` gave you a nice output saying your installation is working correctly, right? Then you should move on with the tutorial, that's all the `hello-world` container can do.